# Counting Specific Values

Tags: r, database, function

I have a data set and I'm trying to figure out how to count the females in it. This is an example of what it looks like.

```
     Income   Career   Age   Sex
1.   39540    Lawyer   20    F
2.   45098    Teacher  65    F
3.   54565    Doctor   45    M
4.   48356    Teacher  26    M
5.   68959    Nurse    32    F
```

I'll call this example.test

So I think I figured out how to get the data by itself by doing example.test(example.test$Sex =f) but I kept getting errors when I tried writing it out in similar forms. My goal is to get the exact amount of Females and males in this data set but I'm not sure how to go about it or which function is the correct one to use.

Comment: `table(example.test$Sex)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways. Here's one of them using base R:

```
table(example.text$Sex)
F M 
3 2
```

Another one:

```
summary(as.factor(example.text$Sex))
F M 
3 2
```

Using dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)
count(example.text, Sex)
  Sex n
1   F 3
2   M 2
```

Comment: Thank you! The first method using base R helped me. I almost gave up but this helps a lot. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the library `tidyverse` and return exactly what you want

```
require(tidyverse)

sex_counts<-data%>%
     group_by(Sex)%>% #tells it to do the summary for each unique value of Sex
     summarize(Count=n()) #uses function n() to count each member of each group
```

This should return a table with the titles Sex & Counts and have a row for each gender and the number of rows for each gender in the Counts column

Comment: You can use any of the three methods above. The reasonsthat I feel the 'tidy' way is most useful: 1 it uses real words to describe what is happening such that reviewing the code takes less time for the human brain to discern. 2 It returns what you want in another table with useful labels ready to pass on into other calculations or visualizations 3. Best practices are the right way to go

Comment: Only dplyr is needed here. No need to load the whole tidyverse

Comment: Agreed, I referred to the tidyverse in the description talking about the conceptual platform, considering tidy methods. As for loading packages,  in my experience it is rare to work where the data is this compact, and typically I use  multiple tidy packages when doing work, so I tend to be lazy and load the whole shebang. I

Comment: I do the same  ..